# Java : Appending extra tokens dynamically to a String

Tags: java, file-io

I am parsing an File , sometimes i get a small line or big line .
Is it possible to append Line with extra tokens incase if the line is small ??

This is my program

```
private static String[] LISTOFFIELDS = null;

String fields = "A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|I|J|K|L|M|N|O|P|Q|R|S|T|U|V|W|X|Y|Z";

String line = "OIUU||HHH|INBVC INB|PP|NN|OO|PPPPP||";

String[] totaltokens = line.split("\\|", LISTOFFIELDS.length);






private static HashMap<String, Object> ParsedValues(String[] totaltokens) {

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        for (int i = 0; i < LISTOFFIELDS.length; i++) {
            String fieldName = LISTOFFIELDS[i];
            map.put(fieldName, totaltokens[i]);
        }


    }
```

As you can see if the line is small i will get

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

**Here i can avoid ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException if i reduce the String fields  to String fields = "A|B|C|D|E|F|G|H|";**

**Is it possible to avoid the Exception , without doing any modifications to the String fields  ??**

Comment: Use *StringBuilder* instead of *String*.

Comment: Why your `LISTOFFIELDS` is `null`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the length of the string before going to split and getting its substring.

Answer (score 0):

Just reduce the number of iterations in your loop:

```
int size = Math.min(LISTOFFIELDS.length, totaltokens.length);
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String fieldName = LISTOFFIELDS[i];
    map.put(fieldName, totaltokens[i]);
}
```